# Order by desc not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a profile view where it lists all questions/blog posts that was submitted by the user. In the other views the `order("created_at desc")` works properly without any bugs whatsoever. However, in my profile view even though I wrote `@questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")` It still displays them incorrectly. To exemplify the issue even more here's an image of what's currently happening.

[image]

As you can see, since I defined that questions should be displayed in descending order, shouldn't **New test title number** be displayed first?

My home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.all.order("created_at")
    @questions = Question.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

end
```

The loop I am using in the profile view:

```
                <% @user.questions.each do |question| %>
                    <%= link_to question.title, question_path(question), :class => "ques" %>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <%= link_to question.user.username, question.user, :class => "bg" %>
                    </p>
                    <hr/>
                <% end %>
```

**P.S:** `@blogs` does the same thing as well.

Comment: Try using Blog.order("created_at desc") instead of Blog.all.order("created_at desc").

Comment: Maybe change `@user.questions` to `@questions` object you already created too. You might also want to check the sql created by that `Question.all.order('created_at DESC').to_sql`

Comment: Do you have any default_scopes in Models ?

Comment: @IslamAzab I can not change the `@user.questions` because it'll display every question in the database. I just want to display the questions that were asked by that specific user. As I said, it works properly on my other views I just don't know why it doesn't work inside my profile view.

Comment: Try changing `<% @user.questions.each do |question| %>` to `<% @user.questions.order('created_at DESC').each do |question| %>`

Comment: That's because I did not display the date but if you want to know, the **Old test title number** was created at 2016-02-26 15:07:53 and the **New test title number** was created at 2016-02-28 12:12:38

Comment: @Pavan , can you post it as an answer so that I mark it as solved?

Comment: Yep! Posting it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have defined `@questions = Question.all.order('created_at DESC')` in the `profile` method but you are **not using it in the view** (you have `@user.questions` in the view which isn't the same as `@questions`). Also `@questions` gives you **all the questions not the particular user questions**. You should change it to below

```
@questions = @user.questions.order('created_at DESC')
```

And in the view

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= link_to question.title, question_path(question), :class => "ques" %>
  <p class="pull-right">
  <%= link_to question.user.username, question.user, :class => "bg" %>
  </p>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
```